# Обновление React Component (Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Не могу понять логику работы кода. Код ниже должен показывать последнее обновление данных и находится в асинхронной функции в `action` (Redux), `date` передается в `state` и выводится на экран через `componentDidMount`. Проблема в том , что не при пересборке не при обновлении проэкта это значение не перезаписывается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему оно не обновляется и как им можно управлять?

```
let currentWeather = {
   date : (() => {
    let time = new Date() 
    let date = moment(time).startOf('hour').fromNow(); 

    //moment это api , который форматирует время и показывает, сколько минут прошло от time
    return date;       
  })()
}
```

полный код объекта

```
let currentWeather = //First item of current weather
{
  tempF : `${Math.ceil(currentData.data.main.temp) }`,
  tempC : `${ Math.ceil(currentData.data.main.temp - 273.15)}`,
  description : currentData.data.weather[0].description,
  date : (() => {
        let time = new Date()
        let date = moment(time).startOf('hour').fromNow();

        return  date

  })(),
  name : currentData.data.name,
  humidity : currentData.data.main.humidity +'%'
}
```

Это значение обновляется самостоятельно каждый час, возможно это связано с тем, что я запрашиваю погоду на **open weather app** и потом меняю данные в этом объекте.

Comment: Это значение обновляется самостоятельно каждый час, возможно это связано с тем,  что я запрашиваю погоду на open weather app и потом меняю данные в этом объекте

Comment: Почему бы не добавить простой метод внутри которого через `setInterval` будет вызываться метод каждый час на обновление погоды, а данные записывать в стейт, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод жизненного цикла компонента `componentDidMount` отрабатывает только один раз (после первого рендера). В вашем случае лучше использовать `componentDidUpdate`. Подробнее [тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).